# Finding valid neighbors in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

So, I have a 4x4 2D array (it will always be these dimensions). Starting with a location on the array, some row and column, I want to find all of its valid neighbors. So far, I have a really clunky implementation.

```
//add row
    if ( !((row + 1) > 3)) {
        //do stuff
    }
    //sub row
    if ( !((row - 1) < 0)) {
        //do stuff
    }
    //add col
    if ( !((col + 1) > 3)) {
        //do stuff
    }
    //sub col
    if ( !((col - 1) < 0)) {
        //do stuff
    }
... and so on
```

This is brutal. I feel like I do not need to check every single neighbor when I start by knowing the location of the element. Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on what `//do stuff` is. Can you change it all to one line?

Comment: If a location is a valid neighbor (reaches do stuff), it just adds the row,column location to a list. Or to be more specific, creates an Location(row,col) object, and adds that to a list.

Comment: Unsolicited => I would try to keep your code positive; meaning negate your `!`s. For instance, `if(!((col-1)<0))` becomes `if((col-1)>=0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately by writing code you are telling a computer what to do and the computer doesn't know anything more than what you tell it.

You can automate this kind of thing a little with nonstandard loop logic though I guess:

```
for (int coff = -1; coff < 3; coff += 2) {
    for (int roff = -1; roff < 3; roff += 2) {

        if (    col + coff >= 0 &&
                col + coff < array.length &&
                row + roff >= 0 &&
                row + roff < array[row].length) {

            // do stuff with array[col + coff][row + roff]

        }
    }
}
```

That loop structure will flip the column and row offset from -1 to 1 and then break when they become 3 on the 3rd iteration.

But note that in your code, checking against !(stuff) > 4 will give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception because remember the last index is 4 - 1.

Answer (score 3):

For any 2D array `cellValues[][]` of `(x,y)` dimensions below code can be used for getting all 8 neighbors for any cell `(i,j)`. Code will return `0` by default.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getNeighbors(int i, int j, int x, int y, int[][] cellValues) {
    ArrayList<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();

    if(isCabin(i, j, x, y)) {
        if(isCabin(i + 1, j, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i+1][j]);
        if(isCabin(i - 1, j, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i-1][j]);
        if(isCabin(i, j + 1, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i][j+1]);
        if(isCabin(i, j - 1, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i][j-1]);
        if(isCabin(i - 1, j + 1, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i-1][j+1]);
        if(isCabin(i + 1, j - 1, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i+1][j-1]);
        if(isCabin(i + 1, j + 1, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i+1][j+1]);
        if(isCabin(i - 1, j - 1, x, y))
            neighbors.add(cellValues[i-1][j-1]);
    }
    return neighbors;
}

public static boolean isCabin(int i, int j, int x, int y) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (i >= 0 && i <= x && j >= 0 && j <= y) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it: a method that gets a list of x,y pairs for valid neighbors, given an arbitrary `[x,y]` point and generalized to any array size:

```
public List<int[]> getNeighbors(x, y, maxX, maxY) {
    neighbors = new ArrayList<int[]>;
    if x > 0:
        neighbors.add({x-1, y});
    if y > 0:
        neighbors.add({x, y-1});
    if x < maxX:
        neighbors.add({x+1, y});
    if x < maxY:
        neighbors.add({x, y+1});
    return neighbors;
}

[...]

for (int[] coords : getNeighbors(x, y, 4, 4)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I like this idea. Maybe not the most efficient for very large matrices though.

Comment: Why not? Its runtime is O(1) no matter how large the matrix is, as long as you only need the neighbors of a single cell.

Comment: Yeah, true, I guess I just looked at it compared to the conditions on their own in which case there is just more things. And I gotta say it's the most readable syntax around whatever `// do stuff` does.

Comment: Actually I see adding them to a list is what the OP told you it's supposed to do so nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

What constitutes a valid neighbor?

If all you want is to retrieve all the neighbors of a cell within the bounds of the array (including diagonals), this will suffice.

```
public List<Element> getNeighbors( int x, int y ) {
    List<Element> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();

    for( int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i ) {
        for( int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j ) {
            if( i == 0 && j == 0 ) {
                continue;
            }
            if( i + x >= 0 && i + x < array.length &&
                j + y >= 0 && j + y < array[0].length ) {
                    // we found a valid neighbor!
                    neighbors.add( array[i][j] );
            }
        }
    }

    return neighbors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it would be to have a seperate method.

```
public void example(int changeSign, boolean shouldCheckRow,boolean shouldCheckColumn){
    int num = 4;
    if(changeSign < 0)
        num = 0;
    if(shouldCheckRow)
        //adding a negative is the same as subtracting so if you add -1, you're really subtracting by one.

        if(!((row + changeSign) < num))
            //do stuff
    else
        if(!((col + changeSign) < num))
            //do stuff
}
```

And the method calls would be

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int shouldTestRight = 1;
    int shouldTestLeft = -1;
    int shouldTestUp = 1;
    int shouldTestDown = -1;
    // so if you want to test up or right, the first parameter should be positive
    // if you want to test for down or left, the first parameter should be negative
    // this is because the negative will flip the sign.
    // if you should change the row, the second parameter should be true
    // if you should change the column, the third parameter should be true.
    example(shouldTestRight,true,false);
    example(shouldTestLeft,true,false);
    example(shouldTestUp,false,true);
    example(shouldTestDown,false,true);
}
```

Of course, you don't have to include the extra ints in the method you're calling from but I did it for extra code readability.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
public int[4][4] array2d;
//don't forget to fill it!

private void adjustNeighbors(int xCoord, int yCoord) {

    for (int yi = y-1; yi <= yCoord+1; yi++) {         //loop through the neighbors

        for (int xi = x-1; xi <= xCoord+1; xi++) {

            try {

                if (!(xCoord != xi && yCoord != yi)) {
                    array2d[y][x]++;  //do whatever you want to all the neighbors!
                } 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // something is out of bounds
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: variables x and y do not exist in your code, yet you assign y - 1 and x - 1 to the indexes in your for loops.  makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FindingNeighboursInMatrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[][] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
                      { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, 
                      { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {

            System.out.println("neightbours of " + array[i][j]);
            int neb[] = findneighbours(i, j, array);
            for (int k = 0; k < neb.length; k++) {
                if (neb[k] != -1) {
                    System.out.print(" " + neb[k] + ",");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}

public static int[] findneighbours(int i, int j, int matrix[][]) {
    int neb[] = new int[8];
    // top row
    neb[0] = getvalue(i - 1, j - 1, matrix);
    neb[1] = getvalue(i - 1, j, matrix);
    neb[2] = getvalue(i - 1, j + 1, matrix);

    // left element

    neb[3] = getvalue(i, j - 1, matrix);

    // right element

    neb[4] = getvalue(i, j + 1, matrix);

    // bottom row
    neb[5] = getvalue(i + 1, j - 1, matrix);
    neb[6] = getvalue(i + 1, j, matrix);
    neb[7] = getvalue(i + 1, j + 1, matrix);

    return neb;

}

public static int getvalue(int i, int j, int matrix[][]) {
    int rowSize = matrix.length;
    int colSize = matrix[0].length;

    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > rowSize - 1 || j > colSize - 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return matrix[i][j];
}}
```